# Can`t build gradle project with org.springframework.boot 1.5.19.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I`m using plugin 'org.springframework.boot' in my Gradle project. After updating to 1.5.19.RELEASE version I got an error when trying to build my project:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
>
> - Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.19.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
>     Required by:
>       project :

I use also other plugins:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'idea'
id 'jacoco'
id 'maven-publish'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.19.RELEASE'
id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'
```

}

When I use 1.15.18.RELEASE the project builds successfully.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that Gradle cannot resolve any dependencies as you haven't configured any repositories in your `build.gradle` file. Spring Boot releases are published to Maven Central so you should be able to correct the problem by adding the following to `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I always add `mavenCentral()` in my `build.gradle` file.  It is strange but today all works fine. But until today, I could not build my project for a week. Maybe spring repository was temporarily unavailable.